# React js: Can´t send first object in array as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to build an small React.js application and my component structure looks like this:

```
MainComponent
    - CategoryList
        -Category
    - ItemsList 
        -Item
```

My MainContent component does an ajax request for its state data in the `componentDidRender:` which returns this object:

```
data:[
Object[0]
 -name
 -items[]
,
Object[1],
Object[2]
]
```

Now, I want my CategoryList to write out all the Categories by name, which works just fine, but I also want to print out the items of the selected category. This is my ItemsList component:

```
 var ItemsList = React.createClass({
    render:function(){

         var itemNodes = this.props.category.items.map(function(item){
            return (
                <Item name={item.name} />
            );
        });

        return(
            <div className="itemList">
            {itemNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

And this is how I pass on the "category"-property from my the parent component

```
<ItemsList category={this.state.data[0]} />
```

I get an error say "Can´t read property items of undefined" meaning that the category prop never was assigned. I know that this.state.data contains an array of objects so I don´t see the error here.

What do I do wrong?

EDIT: Per request, this is my MainComponent:

```
var MainComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount:function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            url: '/categories',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
                this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this)

        });
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <CategoryList categories={this.state.data} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
            <ItemsList category={this.state.data[0]} />
            </div>
        </div>

        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your main component initializes the state with an empty array in `data`. A render would always fail because there is no `this.state.data[0]`.

One would probably reply that the ajax request will provide the value for this state property `data` (supposing that your web service is providing a valid array). **However**, this only happens after the response was received from the server, which will not happen after the first render.

If the information was available immediately, one could either `setState` on the method [`componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) or the component constructor, so as to avoid triggering a second render:

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It
>   is called before render(), therefore setting state synchronously in
>   this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any
>   side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

In this case, since we are waiting for remote information, the React documentation still recommends the use of [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), as well employed here:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

Therefore, the component's render method must be able to handle the missing state variable. There are multiple ways to approach this, but preventing the nested element from being rendered until we have `data` is the easiest approach. With some additional logic, the application could inform the user that the particular component is loading.

```
render() {
    return (
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <CategoryList categories={this.state.data} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          {this.state.data.length > 0 &&
            <ItemsList category={this.state.data[0]} />
          }
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can corroborate the previous answer.
Modern (2023) React tells you to use functional components. So, if you want to upload data from a server to render it inside a component you need to use so-called 'hooks' named 'useEffect' and 'useState'.

So first you import them:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
```

Next, you create a functional component and initialize 'state' and 'set_state function' inside a component:

```
export default function FuctionName() {
   let [ value, set_value ] = useState([]) 
}
```

This would create the 'value' variable which would preserve its state across renders.

Then, you make a fetch request (before the component's return statement) (but you need to put it inside of the useEffect function for a consistent behavior):

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('url')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(server_data => {
        set_value(server_data);
        })}
, [])
```

Now, you see why we need state: because we need to store data returned from the server inside a variable and we need this data to preserve across renders.
Also, you think that now you can use your data inside the component's return render like this:

```
return (
    <h1>the data from server: {value.name_of_key}</h1>
)
```

But you encounter the error of 'reading undefined'.

First, check if the server returns the correct type of object. Put a console.log statement inside the fetch request:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('url')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(server_data => {
        set_value(server_data);
        console.log(server_data);
        })}
, [])
```

It should be a list with objects inside, like: [{}, {}, {}].

If it is, then the problem is that component renders before it receives the data from the server. The component will first render, then receive the data from the server. If you call the state variable inside the render statement it will call the empty state.

So, in order to mitigate it, your code should be ready to render both the empty state and the state with data. The easy way to do so would be conditional rendering. Render the component with data only if there is data to render:

```
return (
    {value && <h1>the data from server: {value.name_of_key}</h1>}
)
```

the 'value &&' part lets you implement the logic:

- if the value (data from the server) is empty don't render anything (thus do not call any keys from data)
- if the value is not empty, render the component which calls to data

Why is that so? The '&&' expression (a and b) evaluates from right to left. If first variable evaluates to 'false', then it does not go further and stops there. The initial state of variable 'value' is an empty object ('let [ value, set_value ] = useState([])' - remember?). So, when the server has not returned data yet on the first render, the expression 'value &&' evaluates to 'false' and does not render the right part of the expression. When the server has returned the data, it calls the 'setState' function with data and forces to render the component the second time. The second time expression 'value &&' evaluates to 'true' and React goes to the right part of the expression and actually renders the component with data. You can check this process by placing console.log statement inside the fetch request and inside the return statement and you will see the order of functions resolutions.

Hope it helps.
Also, check out the article:
https://daveceddia.com/react-before-render/

Happy coding >>