# Reactjs: How to fetch data to loaded before the component is mounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Something weird is happening, I've been reading the React docs and they talk about the lifecycle and how you can do somestuff before your component is rendered. I am trying, but everything I try is failing, always the component makes the render first and after calls componenWillMount, ..didMount, etc.. and after the call of those functions, the render happens again.

I need to load the data first in order to fill the state because I don't want initial state to be `null`, I want it with data since the initial rendering.

I am using Flux and Alt, here is the

**action**

```
@createActions(flux)
class GetDealersActions {

  constructor () {
    this.generateActions('dealerDataSuccess', 'dealerDataFail');
  }

  getDealers (data) {
    const that = this;
    that.dispatch();
    axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}/get-dealers/get-dealers`)
      .then(function success (response) {
        console.log('success GetDealersActions');
        that.actions.dealerDataSuccess({...response.data});
      })
  }
}
```

then the **store**

```
@createStore(flux)
class GetDealersStore {

  constructor () {
    this.state = {
      dealerData : null,
    };
  }

  @bind(GetDealersActions.dealerDataSuccess)
  dealerDataSuccess (data) {
    this.setState({
      dealerData : data,
    });
  }

}
```

and the **component**

```
@connectToStores
export default class Dealers extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    title : React.PropTypes.func,
  }

  static contextTypes = {
    router : React.PropTypes.func,
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal : false,
      dealerData : this.props.dealerData,
    }
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    GetDealersActions.getDealers();
    this.setState({
      dealerData : this.props.dealerData.dealersData,
    })
  }

  static getStores () {
    return [ GetDealersStore ];
  }

  static getPropsFromStores () {
    return {
      ...GetDealersStore.getState(),
    }
  }

  render () {

    return (<div>
          <div style={Styles.mainCont}>
            {!!this.props.dealerData ?
              this.props.dealerData.dealersData.map((dealer) => {
                return (<div>HERE I AM RENDERING WHAT I NEED</div>);
              }) : <p>Loading . . .</p>
            }
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

as you can see in the component part I have this

```
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal : false,
      dealerData : this.props.dealerData,
    }
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    GetDealersActions.getDealers();
    this.setState({
      dealerData : this.props.dealerData.dealersData,
    })
  }
```

which is telling me that `dealerData is undefined` or `can not read property of null`.

All I need is to know a technique where I can fetch the data before the initial renders occurs. So I can filled out the `state` and the start working with that data.

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30329418/1233251

Comment: @E_net4 there is my issue: `Invoked once, both on the client and server, immediately before the initial rendering occurs. If you call setState within this method, render() will see the updated state and will be executed only once despite the state change.` that got me confused.

Comment: @E_net4 in my code I already add an conditional statement and everything as in that question and not working. See my code, try to help me, please.

Comment: You probably have a type error that prevents the program from running properly.

Answer (score 4):

React does guarantee that state assignments in `componentWillMount` will take place before the first render. As you well stated in the comments:

> Invoked once, both on the client and server, immediately before the initial rendering occurs. If you call setState within this method, render() will see the updated state and will be executed only once despite the state change.

However, the asynchronous actions requested there will not immediately update your store. Calling `GetDealersActions.getDealers();` will issue that the store is updated with new content, but the response will only arrive later in the event queue. This means that `this.props.dealersData` does not change during the function and `setState` will attempt to read property "dealersData" of an undefined property. Regardless, the requested content cannot be visible at the first render.

My advice is the same as the one in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30330315/1233251). Preventing the component from rendering that content until it becomes available, as you did, is an appropriate thing to do in a program. Alternatively, render a loader while your "dealersData" hasn't arrived.

---

For solving your particular problem, remove that `setState` from `componentWillMount`. All should work well if your parent component is properly listening for changes and propagating them to the children's props.

```
componentWillMount () {
  GetDealersActions.getDealers();
}
```

Comment: but still the first render happens, and then  `componentWillMount ()` is called. After that, the program renders again.

Comment: By React's contract, that is impossible. Either you have traced another React object being rendered, or in the worst case we have a strange bug.

Comment: I am waiting this data from the Database, will be because of that ?

Comment: It cannot be that. JavaScript is asynchronous, so no function would wait for responses from a server.

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025435/why-componentwillmount-is-called-after-rendering/33025680#33025680

Comment: Look, you seem to have made two very similar questions posing the same problem. Is there any good reason for that besides "being desperate" for a solution in code?

Comment: one is with one store, and the other has 2 stores.

Comment: That doesn't really make the answers any different, you know. Whether the component has to wait for one or more requests for a store to be updated, all this is asynchronous and cannot happen before the first render unless you delay the component's mount.

Comment: I tough it was possible error in stores. Look, the way I have my code now, the initial render is ok, but as componentWillMount is called after the 1st render, then if I use any of the other lifecycle methods, the app crashes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92168/discussion-between-e-net4-and-nietzscheprogrammer).

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I use to receive data from server and display it

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items2 : [{}],
            isLoading: true
        }

    }

componentWillMount (){
 axios({
            method: 'get',
            responseType: 'json',
            url: '....',

        })
            .then(response => {
                self.setState({
                    items2: response ,
                    isLoading: false
                });
                console.log("Asmaa Almadhoun *** : " + self.state.items2);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("Error *** : " + error);
            });
    })}

 render() {
   return(
       { this.state.isLoading &&
                    <i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>

                }
                { !this.state.isLoading &&
            //external component passing Server data to its classes
                     <TestDynamic  items={this.state.items2}/> 
                }
         ) }
```

Comment: Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the ProfileController component.